# FLUTTER Task with timer running in background

Tags: android, flutter, dart, countdowntimer

I have **UI** like this, and we can see timer running in my apps.

[image: UI UX]

And here's **code** of the timer :

```
TimerCountdown(
  onEnd: () {
    getTrxResponse();
    setState((){});
    if (trxStatus.contains('Pending')) {
      failedUpdate();
      setState((){});
    }
  },
  enableDescriptions: false,
  format: CountDownTimerFormat.hoursMinutesSeconds,
  endTime: now.add(
      const Duration(hours: 00, minutes: 30, seconds: 00)),
  timeTextStyle: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black45,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 12),
  colonsTextStyle: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 8),
  spacerWidth: 2,
),
```

The **target** is when the timer on End will updating status transaction, then if status still 'Pending' app will sent failed transaction to backend.

The **problem** is when the apps get force closed by user, it will make the timer stop running and will not sent anything to backend.

Is there something I can do to make the timer running in background?

Or I used a wrong method?

Answer (score 0):

My take on this:

If its a sensitive process that has to be done and confirmed by the User, and considering the multiple problems that can happen to the human user to complete the transaction on time, I would save the state in the backend like so:

1- On transaction start => save a temporal variable in the database linked to the user id and transactionID like ==>  expireOn = DateTimeToExpire & transactionDone = false

2- In the frontend (your app) Set a recurring Timer to check the state in the server. IF currentDateTime > expireOn AND transactionDone = false ==> report a problem ELSE success.

3- onApp start / load do a check if you have pending transactions in the server and check if point #2 above is successfull or if you need to inform of pending or canceled transactions

with these steps you handle the problem of user closing/deleting the app, and notify or remind if they have pending transactions

Comment: does it become vulnerable if using FE to process expired transaction?